# Accept friend request on Skype4Py

Tags: python, skype, skype4py

can someone help me with automatically accepting a friend request with Skype4Py?
Right now I'm using

```
def UserAuthorizationRequestReceived(user):
    user.IsAuthorized = true
```

and

```
skype.UserAuthorizationRequestReceived = UserAuthorizationRequestReceived
```

But it doesn't seem to be working
Thanks!

(Documentation: http://skype4py.sourceforge.net/doc/html/)

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation for `Skype4Py::utils::EventHandlingBase`](http://mediabox.grasp.upenn.edu/roswiki/doc/api/python_skype/html/classSkype4Py_1_1utils_1_1EventHandlingBase.html):

> 1. C{On...} properties.
>
>    This method lets you use any callables as event handlers. Simply assign them to C{On...}
>       properties (where "C{...}" is the name of the event) of the object whose events you are
>       interested in. For example::
>
>    ```
>     import Skype4Py
>
>     def user_status(Status):
>         print 'The status of the user changed'
>
>     skype = Skype4Py.Skype()
>     skype.OnUserStatus = user_status
>    ```

You need to attach the function to `skype.OnUserAuthorizationRequestReceived` instead.

Hopefully, you're doing some check to make sure that your application will not be the target of spam attacks because you're accepting *all* requests.

Comment: @AndrewWong No, you're attaching to `skype.UserAuthorizationRequestReceived`, not `skype.OnUserAuthorizationRequestReceived`.