# Skype4Py with Sevabot: Auto Add Contact Requests

Tags: python, skype4py

How do implement Skype4Py with Sevabot to make it auto add contacts when they request. I am new to python and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking for code **must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924794/accept-friend-request-on-skype4py) it is explained how to achieve this with skype4py